# Regex to find out Lua strings

Tags: regex, lua

Currently we need to find out the strings in our Lua files. I wrote this regex:

```
\\[\\[[^\\[\\]]*\\]\\]|"[^\\"]*"
```

But it's not good enough, it does not match strings that contain "[" or "]" or "\"".

Can someone help?

Comment: Lua strings can also be: `[====[this is a string]====]` or `[=[this is also a string]=]`.

Comment: Yes, but we don't have this kind of lua strings in files, if we do, and we can change them to [[stirng]]. But we can't change the contents of strings.

Comment: Which language are you using to parse?

Comment: I wrote a small program in c#.

Comment: I am using c# to test it right now, if it's ok, we will rewrite it to python, the translate tool on our server is wrote in python.

Comment: Try [`\[[^[\]]*\[(?>[^[\]]+|\[(?<c>)|](?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))][^[\]]*]|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%5b%5e%5b%5c%5d%5d*%5c%5b(%3f%3e%5b%5e%5b%5c%5d%5d%2b%7c%5c%5b(%3f%3cc%3e)%7c%5d(%3f%3c-c%3e))*(%3f(c)(%3f!))%5d%5b%5e%5b%5c%5d%5d*%5d%7c%22%5b%5e%22%5c%5c%5d*(%3f%3a%5c%5c.%5b%5e%22%5c%5c%5d*)*%22&i=%5b%3d%3d%3d%3d%5bthis+is+a+string%5d%3d%3d%3d%3d%5d%0d%0a%5b%3d%5bthis+is+also+a+string%5d%3d%5d%0d%0a%5bstring%5d%0d%0a%22some+string%22). It will not match just `[string]`-like strings, only those with balanced number of square brackets and count of 2+.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to remove slashes rather than trying to come up with a regex to handle them (which is likely to require negative lookbehind expressions). Since you are using regex (and not Lua patterns), something like this would work in Perl:

```
for my $s (qw([[text]more]] [=[text]]more]=] [=[text]] 'text' 'text\'more' 'text\\\\'more' "text" "text\"more" "text\\\\"more" "text'more")) {
  (my $c = $s) =~ s/\\\\/  /g; # remove escaped slashes
  $c =~ s/\\./  /g; # removed escaped non-slashes as they make no difference for string well-formedness
  print("$s => ", $c =~ m/^(?:\[(=*)\[.*?\]\1\]|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")$/ ? 1 : 0, "\n");
}
```

This prints:

```
[[text]more]] => 1
[=[text]]more]=] => 1
[=[text]] => 0
'text' => 1
'text\'more' => 1
'text\\'more' => 0
"text" => 1
"text\"more" => 1
"text\\"more" => 0
"text'more" => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, this regex works for me:

`(?<!--)\[(=*)\[.*?\]\1\]|"((\\.)|[^"\\])*?"|'((\\.)|[^'\\])*?'`

Matching Lua's “Long bracket” string syntax

`\[(=*)\[.*?\]\1\]`

Comment: Yes, they also matches strings like [string]. They are not lua strings.

Comment: You might note that this is helpless if the long bracket string is multiline, unless DOTALL is specified. If other contexts are necessary, this slight alteration fixes that: \[(=*)\[((.|[\r\n])*)\]\1]